# How to click on a button in a web table based on a value from another column

Tags: selenium

I need to search for a value in a web table and when the value is found I should click on the 'Update' button beside that value

I am using the following code but it is not working.

```
   WebElement table = driver.getDriver().findElement(By.id("KSTable166Summary_Main"));

    List<WebElement> buValue = table.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

    for (WebElement webElement:buValue)
    {
        System.out.println(webElement.getText());
        if (webElement.getText().contains(BU))
        {
            driver.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(text(),'"+BU+"')]/following-sibling::td//a[@class='text_button']")).click();
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: are u getting an error stacktrace? Add the relevant html source to the question.

Comment: Relevant `HTML` please.

Comment: Is this code line `//td[contains(text(),'"+BU+"')]` returning something?